# Why does creating a string from multiple objects fail after joining the first two objects

Tags: java, multithreading

Today, I encountered a problem when I tried to combine multiple "variables" or objects, like the following example code:

```
String stuff = "blah blah" + amazingness.getName() + " fantabulous code: " + address.
```

The above example works fine normally, but it does not work in my case.

So basically, I have a server which receives data via UDP means. Now, in order to use UDP, I have to create many threads, so the application does not hang. I don't know if the problem has anything to do with multiple threading, since the processor randomly runs the threads in a random order.

I am using java version 1.8 update 05.
Here is the code in my method.

```
String message = "Client" + c.name + "(" + c.getID() + ") @" + c.address.toString() + ":" + c.port + "disconnected";
```

Where:`c.name` is "Classic", `c.getID()` returns a random number, `c.address.toString()` returns the client's ip address, and `c.port` is the client's port.

When I run the code, I get a message of "Client Classic" and nothing else.
The expected message is: `"Client Classic(1932) @ 70.40.423.110:8112 disconnected"`
Here is a screen shot:
[image: Screen shot of inline message]

Where has the other values gone?

Now I start to think it may be because referencing other classes messes up the process of adding more values to the string.

So I try to get the values before setting the message string

```
String message = "";
    String name = c.name;
    int cID = c.getID();
    String address = c.address.toString();
    int port = c.port;
    message = "Client " + name + "(" + cID + ") @ " + address + ":" + port + "disconnected";

    System.out.println(message);
```

Where:`String name` is Classic, `cID`is a random number, `address` is an ip address, and `port` is a port number. All of the variables are not static. Still does not output the desired message:
[image: Image showing the value of the message string]

NOW, I test it again without the threads, just a standalone class:
[image]

IT WORKS PERFECTLY! Now, my question is why does the above result occur and what did I do wrong?

I appreciate the time you have spent reading my question and I hope you can understand it.

Edit 1: I noticed, in the value of message, the end quotations were never added, will look into it.

Edit 2: looks like the fault is in the name variable, although I have no idea why.

Edit 3: Looks like the name variable contains multiple "null" characters, I will look into it.

Edit: I believe I have fixed the problem, I'll contain a rundown:

```
  Since I created a byte array of length 1024 to send through the network, I never trimmed the array before sending.
  Calling "string.trim()" deletes the excess whitespace characters created when I set the variable "name".
  Even though I had found this out without seeing the answer from David, I'll credit him with the correct answer.
```

Comment: Can you explain what a make clean is?

Comment: basically remove all your compiled class files and re-compile.  You code looks OK as far as I can see.

Comment: Doesn't eclipse automatically recompile everything all the time?

Comment: eclipse, try menu->project->clean..

Comment: Hmm, strange problem.  When you debug in the second example, are the values for cID etc set correctly?

Comment: There's rather a large horizontal scrollbar in that debug view.  Have you tried scrolling all the way over to the right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you only see this behavior in Eclipse? I suspect that what is happening is that your `name` variable contains a null (0) character, which is not a problem for Java per se, but may be a problem for SWT (the widget toolkit used by Eclipse).

For example, the following code creates an array filled with zeros, overwrites the first few 0's with some letters, and then constructs a string similarly to your example.

```
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        byte[] badChars = new byte[10]; // all bytes are 0
        String test = "Middle";
        for (int i = 0;i < test.length() && i < badChars.length; ++i) {
            badChars[i] = (byte) test.charAt(i);
        }        
        String a = new String(badChars);        
        System.out.println(a);        
        String p = "Before " + new String(badChars) + " After";
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

The output of this in eclipse is

```
Middle
Before Middle
```

But when I run this within Intellij IDEA, I get

```
Middle
Before Middle After
```

Just as you would expect.

When I add the following code just after the last println above:

```
StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < p.length(); ++i) {
    char ch = p.charAt(i);
    if (ch > 0) {
        b.append(ch);
    }
}

System.out.println(b.toString());
```

I get the following in Eclipse

```
Middle
Before Middle
Before Middle After
```

So I think it is possible that your 'name' contains a null char, which is causing SWT problems when displayed (such as the debugger, or even the console). SWT uses native widgets (and probably native C style strings, meaning null terminated).

Hope this makes sense - try stripping nulls from your string before you print them, even though they shouldn't be significant in Java.

Comment: While this most likely describes the symptom correctly, filtering out null characters is not the correct solution. Since the question states that the problem does not occur in single-threaded use it indicates that there is a serious thread-safety problem at the place where `name` has been constructed. This has to be fixed to ensure that there are no other issues lurking to show up at a later time.

Comment: 1) I was suggesting that stripping nulls was the best solution, rather that it might prove the hypothesis

Comment: Oops, ran out of time editing my comment. ^ wasnt. The single thread use case does not use the same data, so it's not conclusive. I think it more likely that an errant null terminated string is coming from an external library (native perhaps) or data source, rather then the result of a threading issue. The data isn't actually 'bad', in that it is actually valid to have nulls in a Java strings, but in fact I view this as a bug with SWT (at least in the case of my sample code). If the OP is unable to 'fix' the data at the source, filtering the nulls may actually be a valid option.

Comment: After re-reading the question, it seems likely that the name variable is being populated from data coming from a remote server via UDP - in which case it would not surprise me at all if the strings where null terminated.

Comment: Right, in either case it’s the source of `name` which has to be inspected to understand the reason.

Comment: I spent a good 2 hours trying to figure it out. Yes, this was a great answer by the way, and I figured it would be this problem. Instead of the fix you listed above, I simply called "name.trim()" when I set the variable. So thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
String message = String.format("Client %s (%d) @ %s:%d disconnected", name, cID, address, port);
```

Comment: No that does not work, thanks for the answer though, ( I get the same result)